# Fundamental group of boundary divisor of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_3$ be the moduli stack of stable genus $3$ curves defined over $\mathbb{C}$. The stack $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_3$ has

(1) A locally closed substack $D_0$, parameterizing genus $3$ curves obtained by pinching two points on a smooth genus $2$ curve. Its closure $\Delta_0$ can be identified with $[\overline{\mathcal{M}_{2,2}}/(\mathbb{Z}/2)]$.

(2) A locally closed substack $D_1$, parameterizing genus $3$ curves obtained by pinching a smooth genus $1$ curve and a smooth genus $2$ curve at a node. The normalization of its closure $\Delta_1$ can be identified with $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{2,1}}\times\overline{\mathcal{M}_{1,1}}$.

I am not sure how to calculate the abelianization of $$\pi_1(\Delta_0\backslash \Delta_1)?$$

[I think the intersection $\Delta_0\cap\Delta_1$ has two irreducible components $E_1,E_2$, parameterizing further degenerated curves. By homology ($\mathbb{Z}$-coefficeint) of pairs, we have $$H_2(\Delta_0)\to H_2(\Delta_0, \Delta_0\backslash \Delta_1)\to H_1(\Delta_0\backslash\Delta_1)\to H_1(\Delta_0)\to H_1(\Delta_0,\Delta_0\backslash \Delta_1)\to 0$$ If think we can identify $H_i(\Delta_0)$ as $H_i(\overline{\mathcal{M}_{2,2}})^{\mathbb{Z}/2}$, but not sure how to interpret these terms: I think $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}$ are [simply connected](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/galois-covers-of-moduli-of-curves/8E359287EFB8C1C2F98C3B14863A53F9), but is $H_2(\overline{\mathcal{M}_{2,2}},\mathbb{Z})$ calculated?]

[image: sample image]

Comment: It's not true that the closure of $D_1$ is $\bar M_{2,1} \times \bar M_{1,1}$. That's instead the normalization of the closure of the stratum. Same goes for $D_0$. For example, the closure of $D_1$ contains a locus of the form $(M_{1,1}\times M_{1,2} \times M_{1,1})/S_2$, parametrizing a chain of three genus one curves. The inverse image of this locus in $\bar M_{2,1} \times \bar M_{1,1}$ is $M_{1,1}\times M_{1,2} \times M_{1,1}$, so there's an $S_2$ worth of automorphism missing.

Comment: @DanPetersen Thanks! Then it looks a bit more complicated..

Comment: Also, I think $\Delta_0 \cap \Delta_1$ will have a single irreducible component, whose generic point parametrizes a genus two curve with a nodal genus zero curve attached at a point.

Comment: @DanPetersen I think we can also have smooth genus one curve and a nodal genus 2 curve attached at a point?

Comment: You're right - my bad.

Comment: It might be easier to calculate this as a quotient of the fundamental group of $\mathcal M_{2,2}/{\mathbb Z/2}$ (I guess one has to check that the stuff Dan mentioned does not keep us from deforming any loop of the boundary - in the worst case I guess one can try to calculate the image of that subgroup). This group should have a filtration by normal subgroups whose successive quotients are, from top to bottom $\mathbb Z/2$, a genus $2$ mapping class group, the fundamental group of a genus $2$ surface, the fundamental group of a genus $2$ punctured surface.

Comment: Then $G$ and $H$ will give relations, which I guess are two different kinds of Dehn twists. One could try to see where these relations land in this filtration.